# setrawcookie in PHP not working properly in FF and Chrome when domain and path set

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

This works in Safari, FF, Chrome, etc.:

```
setrawcookie('mycookie', 'myvalue', time() + 31556926);
```

This does not work in FF or Chrome:

```
setrawcookie('mycookie', 'myvalue', time() + 31556926, '/', '.localhost');
```

I have been using PHP for quite some time, and have never seen this behavior before.

Comment: stereofrog, the product is not publicly accessible, hence the fake url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now, was an issue with .localhost instead of .somedomain.com - updated the original question to reflect the broken code. (Morning coffee not kicked in yet)